# How to save to Local Storage when splicing data? Ionic 2+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, local-storage

When the user clicks the save button, the user will be taken back to the previous page with the list item that they have selected will be removed. That functionality is there. I can't seem to save that item being removed though. I '.get' the item in the constructor. Once I have done that I then set the data to the save function in the parent save function that occurs when the user selects the button. Thanks

storage-data.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'

@Injectable()
export class StorageData{

    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){

    }

    getDataFour(){
        return this.storage.get('item')
    }

    save(data){
        let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.storage.set('item', newData)
    }

   delete(data){
      this.storage.remove('item');
    }  
}
```

home.ts

```
export class RiderPerformPage {

  item: any;
  saveAttempt: boolean = false;
  peoples: Rider[];

  constructor( public toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, private menu: MenuController, public navParams: NavParams, riders: Riders, public dataService: StorageData) {
    this.rider = navParams.get('item')
    this.peoples = navParams.get('items')

     this.dataService.getDataFour().then((item) => {
        if(item){
          this.peoples = JSON.parse(item)
        }
      })
}
  save(action){
    this.action = action
      this.presentToast()
      this.saveAttempt = true;
      this.peoples.splice(
        this.peoples.indexOf(this.item), 1);
        this.navCtrl.pop();

      this.dataService.delete(this.peoples);
      this.dataService.save(this.peoples);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must pay attention that the storage functions are asynchronous. So you have to use the **then** callback function if you want to save them, after you call delete. Can you show your **delete** and **save** functions?

Comment: updated my post with the delete and save functions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the native storage functions remove and set are asynchronous. So the following happens: Your delete the item but don't wait until it is finished and in the same time you save your data. But because the delete isn't finished at this moment you save the data with the deleted item in it.

I think you don't have to save the data after deleting an item, because the delete command removes the item from the store. Why you want to save after that?

If you still want to save after you delete the data try the following:

**storage-data.ts**

```
save(data): Promise<any> {
    let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
    return this.storage.set('item', newData);
}

delete(data): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.remove('item');
}
```

**home.ts**

```
save(action){
    this.action = action
    this.presentToast()
    this.saveAttempt = true;
    this.peoples.splice(
    this.peoples.indexOf(this.item), 1);
    this.navCtrl.pop();

    this.dataService.delete(this.peoples)
        .then(() => {
            this.dataService.save(this.peoples);
         });
}
```

Comment: When I refresh my page, it's not saving to the local storage and the data is reset.